# ASP.NET MVC pass data from partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, actionresult

How can I pass data from partial view on submit form in ASP.NET MVC.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "BlogPost", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    ................
    @Html.Partial("PostImagesForPost",Model.PostImages)
}
```

*PostImagesForPost* -  partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Blog.Models.PostImage>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.zoom.min.js"></script>

<div>

@{
    List<Blog.Models.PostImage> images =  Model.ToList();

    <ul class="images">

        @foreach (var img in images)
        {
            string parameterValue_small = "~/BlogPhotos/120/" + img.Photo.ToString();
            string parameterValue_big = "~/BlogPhotos/600/" + img.Photo.ToString(); 

            <li>
                <div id="jquery-image-zoom-example">
                    <span data-postid="@img.ID" data-delete="true" class="deletespan"></span>
                    <a href="@Url.Content(parameterValue_big)">
                        <img src="@Url.Content(parameterValue_small)"  data-postid="@img.ID"  class="zm" onclick="$('.jquery-image-zoom img').click()" />
                    </a>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="selectedImagesForDelete" style="display:none;" data-postid="@img.ID" value="@img.ID"  />
                </div>
            </li>
}
    </ul>

}
```

On submit function the parameter *selectedImagesForDelete* is null.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Post post,string[] selectedImagesForDelete)
    {...........}
```

Comment: Make sure in browser view source, checkbox is properly bind, if correct, try to use Request["selectedImagesForDelete"] to get array instead of param

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the fact you're using a partial, and everything to do with how the modelbinder in MVC works. For iterable posted items, the model binder expects field names in the form of `ListProperty[index].ModelProperty`. The problem is that the `Html.*` family of helpers will not create this name properly unless they are passed an indexed value, which you can't achieve with `foreach`. The solution is to simply use `for`, instead:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < images.Count(); i++)
{
    Html.EditorFor(m => image[i].SomeProperty)
}
```

By passing in a value that's indexed (`images[i]`), the helper recognizes that it needs to add the proper indexed html prefix to the name, so that the modelbinder will understand where to stuff the value when it's posted back.

Though, in your case, you seem to actually just be manually specifying the HTML for the fields, which is fine, but you're responsible at that point for getting the name values right.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your name property needs to have indexes in the name:

Create a index variable called index and increment it after each iteration

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedImagesForDelete[index]" value="2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a problem with the javascript file. The checkboxes were never checked.

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="selectedImagesForDelete" value="@img.ID"  />
```

But I resolved that problem and now everything works like expected.

But thanks for trying to help me. I appreciate it.